# How do I correctly declare an address variable in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

I am a novice to Solidity so you will have to bear with me regarding the following question:

I am trying to compile my first smart contract and keep on running into this Declaration issue. How do I correctly declare an address variable in Solidity?

Find below my simple code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

/**
 * @title Owner
 * @dev Set & change owner
 */
contract Gifter {

    address private gifter;
    //address private giftRecipient;
    
    // event for EVM logging
    event OwnerSet(address indexed gifter, address indexed giftRecipient);
    
    // modifier to check if caller is owner
    modifier isGifter() {
        require(msg.sender == gifter, "Gift NOT yours to give away!");
        _;
    }
    
    /**
     * @dev Set contract deployer as owner
     */
    constructor() {
        gifter = msg.sender; // 'msg.sender' is sender of current call, contract deployer for a constructor
        emit OwnerSet(address(0), gifter);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Change owner
     */
    function giftTo( address giftRecipient ) public isGifter {
        emit OwnerSet(gifter, giftRecipient);
        //gifter = giftRecipient;
        giftRecipient = giftRecipient;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Return owner address 
     * @return address of owner
     */
    function whoWasGifted() external view returns (address) {
        return giftRecipient;
    }
}
```

I keep getting the following error message:

```
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
--> contracts/gifter.sol:45:16
|
45 | return giftRecipient;
| ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `giftRecipient` declaration is commented out.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

/**
 * @title Owner
 * @dev Set & change owner
 */
contract Gifter {

    address private gifter;
    address private giftRecipient;
    
    // event for EVM logging
    event OwnerSet(address indexed gifter, address indexed giftRecipient);
    
    // modifier to check if caller is owner
    modifier isGifter() {
        require(msg.sender == gifter, "Gift NOT yours to give away!");
        _;
    }
    
    /**
     * @dev Set contract deployer as owner
     */
    constructor() {
        gifter = msg.sender; // 'msg.sender' is sender of current call, contract deployer for a constructor
        emit OwnerSet(address(0), gifter);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Change owner
     */
    function giftTo( address _giftRecipient ) public isGifter {
        emit OwnerSet(gifter, _giftRecipient);
        //gifter = giftRecipient;
        giftRecipient = _giftRecipient;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Return owner address 
     * @return address of owner
     */
    function whoWasGifted() external view returns (address) {
        return giftRecipient;
    }
}
```

Noticed how I change the name for the function parameter to be `_giftRecipient` to avoid problems with the declared one.